# Save/Load Matcher with patterns as new pipeline component

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm newby in spacy. Trying now to add a lot of patterns to the **Matcher** and integrate it with pipeline, so then i could just load **Matcher** component from  pipeline and use it, without re-adding a lot of patterns.

I create and save it with the next code:

```
pattern = [{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"IS_PUNCT": True}, {"LOWER": "world"}],[{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"LOWER": "world"}]
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("HelloWorld", None, *pattern)
nlp.add_pipe(matcher)
nlp.to_disk('mynlp')
```

Then i try to load my component and use it:

```
from spacy.language import Language

Language.factories['Matcher'] = lambda nlp, **cfg: Matcher(nlp.vocab, **cfg)

nlp = spacy.load('mynlp')
matcher = nlp.get_pipe("Matcher")

doc = nlp("Hello, world! Hello world!", disable=["Matcher"])
matches = matcher(doc)

print(matches)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id] 
    span = doc[start:end] 
    print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

But result is empty list. I guess, that patterns didn't saved. Is there is something i misunderstood or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline components are runnable like code, so spaCy doesn't attempt to save them to disk. Other people using such a model would be at risk from the potentially arbitrary code in the components. You can see that by inspecting `len(matcher)` before the save and after the load. The meta.json in the saved model has a Matcher pipeline entry, but there's no content for it.

There are several posts from spaCy devs, e.g. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2676#issuecomment-413274806 with guidance on how to add the necessary custom component code to a python package that will distribute your modified pipeline.